# Design Issue: Should UI layer worry about it's backend?

Tags: java, architecture

It is more of a design and architecture question.
 
I am developing a new UI layer for an old system. This system accepts request in particular xml format. Currently request from the new UI layer goes to a data massaging class via controller.
This `Translator/Massaging class` converts UI request xml to desired request format. It adds few deprecated elements and constants to the XML it received from UI layer. 
Request XML from UI is partially similar to the actual back end. But it has to go to the `Translator/Massaging` class to be converted into actual request.
My question does UI layer need to worry about if it's request XML is partially similar to the actual request? Can UI layer just send the data in JSON format to the `Translator/Massaging` and translator class will convert it into the actual request xml?

Answer (score 1):

> My question does UI layer need to worry about if it's request XML is partially similar to the actual request?

No.  As you suggested in your next question, the messaging class can convert the GUI data into an actual XML request.

> Can the UI layer just send the data in JSON format to the messaging class and messaging class will convert it into the actual request XML?

It could.  However, your GUI should have a data model.  The GUI would interact with the data model.  The data model would interact with the messaging class.  There's no need for another data format, unless there's some requirement you're not telling us.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely right about data model. These forms are following data model, I call them `UIModels`. Think of each UIModel as a VO object. Right now `Translator` or `Massaging` class is taking care of placing these `UIModel` xmls in proper place with constant elements to match request xml. Sounds good?

Comment: @Himanshu Yadav: As long as your GUI components can get or set fields in your UIModels, yes.

Comment: One more doubt. These UI models are actually UIModel XMLs which represent VO Objects. Currently I make sure all the field `name` attributes value matches UIModel XML elements.<br/>Then I build the xml with with form values. This form XML is same as model XML. Can I just build a JSON object with form values which matches model XML? Does it sound appropriate?

Comment: @Himanshu Yadav: I don't understand why your GUI model can't be plain old Java objects (POJO)?

Comment: Actually I am building a configurable UI container. It will help business analysts build their own forms. These UI Model XML are for their reference. So that they give the correct field name.

Answer (score 0):

> My question does UI layer need to worry about if it's request XML is partially similar to the actual request? Can UI layer just send the data in JSON format to the massaging class and massaging class will convert it into the actual request xml?

Clearly it could do that.  But that would mean that the "massaging" class has more work to do.

To my mind, you are probably asking the wrong question here.  If I was in your shoes, I'd be asking myself why I can't use the request format for the "old" system directly, or why I can't change the "old" system to accept requests in the "new" format directly.

Or to put it another, ask yourself what is the purpose of implementing a new format, and all of the extra coding and the performance hit of the "massaging".

Unless there is something else going on that you haven't told us, this all sounds a bit unnecessary to me.

Comment: Reason 1: Old system can not be changed is that It is huge and stubborn. Will take a lot of time to figure out impact of the changes.
Reason 2: Request XML it accepts is pretty big and have a lot of constant and deprecated elements. Trying to keep new UI as light as possible so that it can work on smaller devices too.

Answer (score 0):

**Think services!** Any functionality the server offers and is used by the client should be abstracted by a service interface, so that code using this service *never has to worry about its implementation or any protocols involved*. You can then have the actual implementation on the server, and a remote facade implementation for the client, which forwards the request to the server and also handles the responses:

```
interface SomeService {
    public SomeResult doSomething(SomeArguments) throws SomeException; 
}

class SomeServiceServerImpl implements SomeService {
    // server-side implementation
}

class SomeServiceClientFacade implements SomeService {
    // client-side facade, forwards the request, for example to a web service
}
```

The facade can then convert the arguments to XML, call a web service, parse the XML response and convert it back to a result object or exception.

If you use a standardized **RPC (Remote Procedure Call) protocol** (such as SOAP or [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC)), the most elegant way to handle this would be to use a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) with an `InvocationHandler` which does the request [marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) and response unmarshalling in a generic way, allowing you to cheaply create remote service proxies.

Comment: I would say, It is a privileged client. Because this UI layer is part of the EAR.